# include sql files and use minted for highlighting

Tags: minted, include, sql

I write in latex a documentation about a database project.

I would like to include some sql files in my latex document and highlight this files with minted.

My initial approach is the following, but it's only print my `\input` command.

```
\label{included-sql-files}
\section{SQL-Files}
\begin{minted}[lineos, framesep=2mm, fontsize=\small]{sql}
\input{./sql/01.sql}
\end{minted}
```

Maybe anyone else know a good solution for my problem.

Volker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `\inputminted` but I would recommend to define your own command with whatever options you like (see minted documentation page 29):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\newmintedfile[inputsql]{sql}{%
    linenos,
    autogobble,
    breaklines,
}

\begin{document}
    \inputsql{sql/01.sql}
\end{document}
```